# What's up with my logic?

Tags: php, math

I have put together this simple logic to add two numbers, echo the values for a and b then show the answer, it's pretty late here but i cant understand why the answer is NOT the sum of $a + $b. I thought this was ABC stuff but a little help would not go a miss. Thank you in advance.

```
$number_one = mt_rand(1,100);
$number_two = mt_rand(1,100);

function add_numbers($a, $b) 
{
$sum = $a + $b; 
return $sum;
}

echo "What is " . $number_two . " + " . $number_two . "? <br />";
$answer = add_numbers($number_one, $number_two);
echo $answer;
```

Comment: what is the answer if not the sum of those numbers? Please elaborate on the actual behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it was just pointed out I was being extremely stupid and wrote $number_two twice in my function.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its cause is a typo. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a typo...

```
echo "What is " . $number_two . " + " . $number_two . "? <br />";
```

Should be:

```
echo "What is " . $number_one . " + " . $number_two . "? <br />";
                          ^^^
```

Comment: Well, that definitively was a Number Two :-)

Comment: Oh, wow! I literally laughed and cried at the same time, cringing with embarrassment. Normally I debug all my own code, but I looked at that for sooo long and could'nt see it! I think this means it is time for some sleep. Thank you Sean.